# ¿Por qué acc de model.fit () cambia en cualquier momento que lo computemos?

Tags: redes-neuronales, keras

Estaba intentando hacer un entrenamiento modelo con model.fit () para Toxic Comment Copetition y noté algo extraño: ejecuto el código y, al principio, me dio una mala precisión mientras lo ajustaba, algo así como 0.6 ... y luego recordé que tenía que almacenar los resultados de los accesorios para poder trazarlos más tarde. Y mientras lo refinanciaba, noté que el acc se había disparado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cual es la razon ? Esto es realmente importante porque solo recompilaba RocAucEvaluation () y esto para probar diferentes diseños ROC AUC.

Mi código está disponible en [mi página web dedicada](https://github.com/antoinecomp/ToxicCommentsClassifier/) sobre Github.

Answer (score 0):

Ya debes tener la respuesta desde hace 4 meses que se hizo esta pregunta, pero lo importante acá es tener en cuenta que usas un `batch_size` de 64, por lo cual en cada iteración solo está viendo 64 comentarios.

Si los primeros 64 son difíciles de clasificar la precisión será menor y si son fáciles esta subirá, incluso en la misma `epoch`.

Tienes que darle tiempo para que generalice y los resultados sean mas estables.

Comment: Tengo que darle tiempo or darle mas espacio en `batch_size` ?

Comment: Deja la red entrenar por varias epochs, no se preocupe por los cambios en accuracy, eso es normal teniendo un batch_size pequeño.